# How to add a horizontal line on a specified height in a div?

Tags: javascript, css

Suppose I have a div with 500 width and 700 height. How do I put a horizontal line or an image as a background on a specific height?
I have posted it here also http://jsfiddle.net/jt74S/

```
<div id="main">
these are some text and stuff, however the horizontal line/image should not be added with the text, but as a background of these.
</div>

#main {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.75);
    border-radius: 0 3px 0 3px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 20px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/anaida/t57XM/

Set background color and image both in same property.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `background-position` CSS property will work.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rnSDw/1/

You can change the background-position property to a keyword like left, center, etc. or pixels for exact positioning.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example please?

Comment: Thank you for this but I must keep the `background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.75);`

Answer (score 0):

You could make the line as a one-pixel-wide background image of the requisite height, then have it repeat across the page. Or you could make #main position: relative and give it a child div { left:0; right: 0; height: npx; border-bottom: your specifications; }. But hopefully @joeschmidt45's suggestion is a goer and you won't need to do anything so nast^h^h^h^hpragmatic.